# why the dynamic nodes dont respond to click in jstree?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, jstree

I have the following code to display jstree control with ajax data.

---

action method for data in `Home` controller

```
 [HttpGet]
        public JsonResult GetNodeData()
        {
            var tvdata = new List<NodeDataStructure>();
            tvdata.Add(new NodeDataStructure { id = "student1", parent = "#", text = "Single root node", value = "10", @class = "parentNode" });
            tvdata.Add(new NodeDataStructure { id = "student2", parent = "#", text = "Root Node with children", value = "10", @class = "parentNode" });
            tvdata.Add(new NodeDataStructure { id = "student3", parent = "student2", text = "Query1", value = "answerQ1", @class = "cn1" });
            tvdata.Add(new NodeDataStructure { id = "student4", parent = "student2", text = "Query2", value = "answerQ2", @class = "cn1" });

            return Json(tvdata, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

**ViewModel**

```
  public class NodeDataStructure
    {
        public String id { get; set; }
        public string @class { get; set; }
        public string parent { get; set; }
        public string text { get; set; }
        public string value { get; set; }
    }
```

**Index.cshtml**

```
<div id="Div_jstree"></div>

@section Scripts{
    <script src="Scripts/jstree.min.js"></script>
    <script>

        $(document).ready(function () {

            $.ajax({
                url: 'Home/GetNodeData',
                method: 'get',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {

                    $(data).each(function (index, item) {
                        console.log("here");
                    });

                    $('#Div_jstree').jstree({
                        'core': {
                            'data': data
                        }
                    });

                    $(document).on('click', '.cn1', function () {
                        console.log('im here');
                    });
                },
                error: function (x,y,z) { }

            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

I have put the click event in the success part of ajax but the click does not work, whats the problem here and how should I fix it?

```
Here is the generated html but since jstree is dynamic I don't see any use of this.

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>
    <link href="/Content/site.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <link href="/Content/themes/base/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <script src="/Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="Content/themes/default/style.min.css" />


<br><br><br><br>

<div id="Div_jstree"></div>





    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-2.2.0.js"></script>

    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.11.4.js"></script>

    <script src="/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>




    <script src="Scripts/jstree.min.js"></script>
    <script>

        $(document).ready(function () {

            $.ajax({
                url: 'Home/GetNodeData',
                method: 'get',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {

                    $(data).each(function (index, item) {
                        console.log("here");
                    });

                    $('#Div_jstree').jstree({
                        'core': {
                            'data': data
                        }
                    });

                    $(document).on('select_node.jstree', '.cn1', function () {
                        console.log('im here');
                    });
                },
                error: function (x, y, z) { console.log('error'); }

            });


        });
    </script>


<!-- Visual Studio Browser Link -->
<script type="application/json" id="__browserLink_initializationData">
    {"appName":"Chrome","requestId":"2cf16620b2de4718bed3c368cbe7f86b"}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:48985/eae5ba43081c4bce98f0d05ef8143589/browserLink" async="async"></script>
<!-- End Browser Link -->

</body>
</html>
```

here is the generated DOM for (#Div_jstree)

```
<div id="Div_jstree" class="jstree jstree-1 jstree-default" role="tree" aria-multiselectable="true" tabindex="0" aria-activedescendant="student4" aria-busy="false">
   <ul class="jstree-container-ul jstree-children" role="group">
      <li role="treeitem" aria-selected="false" aria-level="1" aria-labelledby="student1_anchor" id="student1" class="jstree-node  jstree-leaf"><i class="jstree-icon jstree-ocl" role="presentation"></i><a class="jstree-anchor" href="#" tabindex="-1" id="student1_anchor"><i class="jstree-icon jstree-themeicon" role="presentation"></i>Single root node</a></li>
      <li role="treeitem" aria-selected="false" aria-level="1" aria-labelledby="student2_anchor" aria-expanded="true" id="student2" class="jstree-node  jstree-last jstree-open">
         <i class="jstree-icon jstree-ocl" role="presentation"></i><a class="jstree-anchor" href="#" tabindex="-1" id="student2_anchor"><i class="jstree-icon jstree-themeicon" role="presentation"></i>Root Node with children</a>
         <ul role="group" class="jstree-children" style="">
            <li role="treeitem" aria-selected="false" aria-level="2" aria-labelledby="student3_anchor" id="student3" class="jstree-node  jstree-leaf"><i class="jstree-icon jstree-ocl" role="presentation"></i><a class="jstree-anchor" href="#" tabindex="-1" id="student3_anchor"><i class="jstree-icon jstree-themeicon" role="presentation"></i>Query1</a></li>
            <li role="treeitem" aria-selected="true" aria-level="2" aria-labelledby="student4_anchor" id="student4" class="jstree-node  jstree-leaf jstree-last"><i class="jstree-icon jstree-ocl" role="presentation"></i><a class="jstree-anchor jstree-clicked" href="#" tabindex="-1" id="student4_anchor"><i class="jstree-icon jstree-themeicon" role="presentation"></i>Query2</a></li>
         </ul>
      </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you solved your problem?

Answer (score 1):

you know that `<div id="Div_jstree"></div>` is your container

and if you are certain that after obtaining ajax results, calling

```
$('#Div_jstree').jstree({'core': {'data': data}});
```

will definitely trigger a change in the DOM structure of your container.

What you can do is that, after calling jstree, perform a

```
$('#Div_jstree').find('li').each(function(){
    //apply a click listerner on each leaf <li> element that is found
    //in #Div_jstree

    if( $(this).find('ul').length <=0 ){
        $(this).click(function(){
            // your click handling logic
        });
    }

});
```

To put it all together, it should look similar to this.
node 1, 3 and 4 should have listeners applied to them.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  var changesIntroducedToContainerAfterAjax = '<ul class="jstree-container-ul jstree-children" role="group">      <li role="treeitem" aria-selected="false" aria-level="1" aria-labelledby="student1_anchor" id="student1" class="jstree-node  jstree-leaf"><i class="jstree-icon jstree-ocl" role="presentation"></i><a class="jstree-anchor" href="#" tabindex="-1" id="student1_anchor"><i class="jstree-icon jstree-themeicon" role="presentation"></i>Single root node</a></li>      <li role="treeitem" aria-selected="false" aria-level="1" aria-labelledby="student2_anchor" aria-expanded="true" id="student2" class="jstree-node  jstree-last jstree-open">         <i class="jstree-icon jstree-ocl" role="presentation"></i><a class="jstree-anchor" href="#" tabindex="-1" id="student2_anchor"><i class="jstree-icon jstree-themeicon" role="presentation"></i>Root Node with children</a>         <ul role="group" class="jstree-children" style="">            <li role="treeitem" aria-selected="false" aria-level="2" aria-labelledby="student3_anchor" id="student3" class="jstree-node  jstree-leaf"><i class="jstree-icon jstree-ocl" role="presentation"></i><a class="jstree-anchor" href="#" tabindex="-1" id="student3_anchor"><i class="jstree-icon jstree-themeicon" role="presentation"></i>Query1</a></li>            <li role="treeitem" aria-selected="true" aria-level="2" aria-labelledby="student4_anchor" id="student4" class="jstree-node  jstree-leaf jstree-last"><i class="jstree-icon jstree-ocl" role="presentation"></i><a class="jstree-anchor jstree-clicked" href="#" tabindex="-1" id="student4_anchor"><i class="jstree-icon jstree-themeicon" role="presentation"></i>Query2</a></li>         </ul>      </li>   </ul>';

  //simulate Ajax call
  $('#Div_jstree').html(changesIntroducedToContainerAfterAjax);

  //apply listeners to leaf nodes

  $('#Div_jstree').find('li').each(function(){

    if( $(this).find('.jstree-node').length <=0 ){
      console.log( $(this).prop('id') );

      $(this).click(function(){
        alert( $(this).prop('id') + " clicked" );
      });
    }

  });


});
```

See it working on CodePen:  http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vLzxpj

Comment: no response from console.log() when i place it in click()

Comment: when i check  data of the success function it showed 4 objects

Comment: @zeelong, if you see data in ajax response, it means that your ajax is successful, so is your web endpoint. After the ajax call, can you inspect $('#Div_jstree'), make sure that there has been expected changes made to the DOM? I suspect that #Div_jstree does not contain any .cn1 elements

Comment: @zeelong, I have formatted your pasted code. There isn't any child elements of class="cn1", that is precisely the reason why the click event is not fired. Are you intending to fire clicks events on li elements?

Comment: yes i need to attach the click events to <li> elements but those <li> must be those two child nodes (note: the json generated all four from that two were parents and another two children of the second parent node)

Comment: @zeelong  to generalize your problem. you only want apply click events to leaf nodes?

Comment: @zeelong, I have modified my answer, if you need specific handling with other child elements inside of the leaf <li> element, i am sure you can figure out what to do in the click handler.

Comment: i have copied exact code but still nothing from console.log()

Comment: @zeelong, I have modfied the code again, and added codepen example.

Answer (score 0):

The `select_node` event would be fired on tree element so the correct way to bind a handler to it in your success callback would be as below.
Check demo - [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ermakovnikolay/bjuqwhef/):

```
...
success: function (data) {

    $('#Div_jstree')
        .on('select_node.jstree',  function () {
            console.log('im here');
        })
        .jstree({
            'core': {
                'data': data
            }
        });

}
```